# "to day" or "to date"?

Tags: phrases

In this sentence,

> My research for *Point of Origin* was some of the most intensive and dangerous I've done to date, and the story I tell here remains the most painful. (Seen at the introduction part of novel, ["Point of Origin"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0425222381), by an American writer)

Can we say "to day" instead of "to date" in the above sentence? Because "today" comes from "to day", though I'm not sure about whether we can still use "to day".

Comment: While "today" does technically come from "to" + "day", the meaning of "to" in this phrase was something more like "at" or "on", which is no longer valid in Modern English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we can’t. *To date* means ‘until now’. *Today* doesn't.

Comment: `Till this day` could be used, no.

Comment: To @BarrieEngland, Neither does "to day" (a space in between)?

Comment: @congliu. Correct.

Comment: @mplungjan I can't image many English speakers saying "Till this day" meaning "to date" or "until now".

Comment: Maybe not today, but it is correct English